# positive definite matrix R code

Tags: r, matrix

I started to code a  positive definite matrix from two vectors. Two vectors are given below

```
ehat = matrix(c(-0.01, -0.10, -0.02, -0.12, -0.004, -0.02, -0.007,  0.004), 8, 1)

Z = matrix(c(-0.07, -0.07, -0.04,  0.10,  0.08,  0.04, -0.01, -0.08), 8, 1)
```

According to algebra, the below code must give a positive definite matrix. But the code in R is not working as it should work. Obviously there is a mistake, but I failed to find one.

Any suggestion please

```
omegahat <- matrix(0,ncol(Z),ncol(Z))

N = length(Z)

q = round(N^1/3)

for (j in 1:q) {
    Gq=matrix(0,ncol(omegahat),ncol(omegahat))

    for (k in (j+1):N)
    {
         Gq <- Gq+(ehat[k]*ehat[(k-j)])*(t(Z[k,])%*%(Z[(k-j),]))

    }

    Gq=1/N*Gq

    omegahat=omegahat+(1-j/q)*(Gq+t(Gq))

}

omegahat
```

Comment: For one, you are assigning a scaler to `Gq`, and I'm guessing `Gq` should be a matrix.

Comment: Also be careful with your order of operations.  If I use 'q = round(N^(1/3))'  I get omegahat to be positive.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This code provides non-conformable arrays  if we assume Z is matrix of 3 variables or more. It is not also a positive definite. Any help

Comment: It produces Error in                                                                                       Gq + (ehat[k] * ehat[(k - j)]) * (t(Z[k, ]) %*% (Z[(k - j), ])) : 
non-conformable arrays
Any help pls